# Trouble Connecting to Google Cloud SQL API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

We are trying to connect to the Cloud SQL API just to monitor/manage the instances at a hight level. We've tried following these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) but we keep getting a 403 using the Java SDK. We also don't see any roles for `Cloud SQL` as stated in that article.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a code sample/commands that you have tried and the exact errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a role to a service account, go to your console, and select "IAM & admin">"IAM", in the member's section select the drop down arrow and select "Cloud SQL Client".

There are many options to connect, the following worked for me - For Unix using TCP: (1)Enable the API (2) Download the correct version for the cloud SQL proxy and change the permissions as instructed. (3) Used Credentials from an authenticated SDK client "To enable the proxy to use your Cloud SDK credentials, you must use the gcloud auth application-default login". Run gcloud auth list.  Optionally the service account above can also be used if required and a credential key furnished.  Get your "Instance Connection Name" from your console, paste it below.

After doing all that I run the following in terminal window 1: 
./cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[**THE FULL INSTANCE NAME**]=tcp:3306 &

In terminal window 2 using a user account that is used to log in to the instance:
mysql -u [[cloudsqlproxy user](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#invocation) or username] --host 127.0.0.1 -p

Your MySQL connection id is 30365
Server version: 5.7.14-....

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>